# how to catch instance_id that is of type class after creating a new server with boto3 with python

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, python-class

I am launching a new ec2 instance with this code:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',
         aws_access_key_id=existing_user.access_id,
         aws_secret_access_key=existing_user.secret_id,
         region_name='eu-west-2')

    instance = ec2.create_instances(
            ImageId="ami-084e8c05825742534",
            MinCount=1,
            MaxCount=1,
            InstanceType="t2.micro",
            KeyName="KeyPair1",
            SecurityGroupIds=[
            'sg-0f6e6789ff4e7e7c1',
            ],
        )

    print('successfully lauched an instance save it to User db')
    print(instance[0])
    print(type(instance[0]))
```

the instance variable returns an instance id of the new ec2 instance
which i am printing which output something like this:

```
ec2.Instance(id='i-03ee6121b4e7846d2')
<class 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance'>
```

I am new to python classes and stuff and not able to access/extract the id which i need to save
to my DB.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

The ec2 class has an attribute which you can print like this or save to DB :

```
print(f'EC2 instance "{ec2.id}"')
```